How to include a shell variable in the file name of a csv from hive
I'm running a script that will be automated to run every quarter so I would like to include the dynamic date variable in the name of the csv output at the end of this script. Here is the relevant snippet, it works fine without the $qtr in the file name, but when I add it to the filename, the resulting .csv is unreadable.
#!/bin/bash

qtr=$(date -d "-2 month" +%Y)Q$(( ($(date -d "-2 month" +%-m)-1)/3+1 ))

hiveconnector -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true;select * from hivetable;" | tr "\\t" "," >file_name_$qtr.csv

Edit: I've tried the following changes to file_name_$qtr.csv:
file_name_${qtr}.csv, file_name_"${qtr}".csv, $"file_name_${qtr}.csv"

Edit 2: It looks like a line break is getting added between the $qtr var and the plain text, even though an echo of file_name_"${qtr}".csv does not show the line break--
Error message:
Can't create file 'C:\...\file_name_2024Q1

.csv'
    
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Edit 3 - Solution:
I was able to solve by Unix EOL Conversion and calling a new variable that held the whole path/filename.

Maybe add echo "qtr: \"$qtr\"" so you can examine the contents.  I would also add curly braces file_name_${qtr}.csv

Always quote your variables: "file_name_$qtr.csv"

Paste your script into shellcheck.net, fix any problems it identifies.

Show the contents of qtr

shellcheck.net says no issues detected on file_name_"${qtr}".csv, but error persists

If there's a problem with $qtr, it might give the wrong filename, but it shouldn't result in an unreadable file. Are you sure that's the only thing that changed between when it works and when it doesn't? You can put set -x to get an execution trace (which'll show the commands a bit differently -- mostly using single-quotes instead of double-quotes) and see how that differs with vs without the quarter name. Also, exactly what's wrong with the file that makes it unreadable? Examine the contents to see what's wrong with the unreadable file.

What do you mean by unreadable? Wrong csv format? Empty? Etc.

Not your problem but regarding tr "\\t" "," - you're having to double the escapes because by using double quotes instead of single (which you should always use until if/when you need to not use them) you're asking the shell to come in and interpret what's between the quotes but you don't actually want the shell to consume the backslash before the t so you're having to add an extra backslash to protect the existing backslash from the shell that you invited in to interpret it. Just don't do that, use tr '\t' ','.

In other parts of your code you're also using using double quotes when you should be using single, and in others still you're using no quotes when you should be using double quotes. It's absolutely crucial to fully understand what types of quotes (single, double, or none) to use in which situations if you're going to do any shell programming - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

strange that I am getting error with .csv but not with .txt so. try to create file with .txt and then rename it to .csv using mv command

.txt gives me the same error

You should post the solution below in Your Answer, not in the question.

Solution: I was able to solve by Unix EOL Conversion and calling a new variable that held the whole path/filename.
